# php sql query multiple condition with Search?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to filter items with its various categories.
I did it by adding conditions in an array, which is like:

```
$condition = array();
if ($conditionA == "something"){
    array_push($condition, "categoryA LIKE '$conditionA'");
}
...
foreach ($condition as $k => $v){
   if($k == 0){
      $filter .= " WHERE " . $v;
   }else{
      $filter .= " AND " .$v;
   }
}

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Table $filter);
```

This is what I've done so far, and those filtering work perfectly fine.
But I want to add a search feature and the method I'm supposed to use is:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH (label ,title, description) AGAINST ('$search' IN BOOLEAN MODE)");
```

If I use the search feature by itself with removing `$result` on the first block, it works perfectly fine as well.
But how would I be able to combine those two?

Comment: `MATCH (label ,title, description) AGAINST ('$search' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` is just another condition why doesn't it work? How did you join? Do you get an error? This looks like it's open to SQL injections. Maybe you want to be using an `or` because full text match is optional?

Comment: Not the answer but your entire `foreach` loop can be replaced by `$filter .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $condition);`

Comment: Just add the `MATCH` condition to the `$condition` array. What problem are you having?